# Print out Multiple Lines from MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, printing, flask, pymongo

Hey guys I'm running this code, and when I launch it up on "/d", I want it to print out the whole database, at the moment its only printing one line and changes to the next Object if I refresh the page, can you help?

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
db = client.fliDb

app = Flask(__name__)

games = db.games
g= games.find()

@app.route('/d', methods = ["GET","POST"])
def content():
for game in g:
    str(game)
    return str(game)
```

Comment: looks like your return statement is inside the loop. as soon as return is called, it completes the function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new PyMongo Cursor each time you request the page, instead of using a global cursor. Also, you need to completely iterate the cursor, instead of returning from inside the loop after the first iteration. Do this:

```
@app.route('/d', methods = ["GET","POST"])
def content():
    g = games.find()
    return '\n'.join([str(game) for game in g)])
```

Comment: And need escaping `html` contents for clear text output. `games.find()` bad idea on browser side. need some limitations for performance.